# Plugin to change incoming url

Tags: development, system-plugin

I am creating a component but need to redirect all incoming requests to the new component. The URL looks like this currently: index.php?option=com_component&view=xxx and when this comes in I want to replace com_component into com_newcomponent, all internal views are the same.

Is this possible by a simple plugin?

Answer (score 1):

```
/**
 * Fucntionality which needs to be triggered on After the system has been loaded.
 *
 * @since 1.0.0
 */
public function onAfterInitialise()
{
    $app = JFactory::getApplication();

    // Frontend only, otherwise return.
    if(!$app->isClient('site'))
    {
        return false;
    }

    $router = $app->getRouter();
    $callback = array($this, 'buildRoute');

    $router->attachBuildRule($callback);
}

public function buildRoute($router, $uri)
{
    $routerClone = clone $router;
    $vars= $routerClone->parse($uri);

    if($vars['option'] == 'com_component1' && $vars['view'] == 'update')
    {
        $uri->setVar('option', 'com_component_new');

    }
}
```

Comment: But this url is for the Joomla updater so it is not always a SEF URL. Does this still work then?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple system plugin, with the event onAfterInitilization() do some very basic checks, e.g. isAdmin, is the component com_component used and if so do the redirect there

Comment: I was writing this but the old url is being kept and viewed an I want to redirect it to the new space

Comment: Found an answer in the yireo plugins book. Always useful a book from Jisse